# electron app fails when defining / requiring various javascript apps

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, require, electron

I am trying to use electron to bundle a web page into an app.

I can do fine with sample applications, but my web page uses jquery and various libraries which depend on jquery in order to operate. On its own, the site works fine in a web browser, but when launching it via electron, I get various javascript errors starting in the libraries' define / export statements.

My electron app is structured as follows:

```
main.js
package.json
app
  index.html
  js/app.js
  js/lib/jquery.js
  js/lib/library1.js
  ...
```

where app contains all of my custom code which relies on the included libraries, and index looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>[TITLE]</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
<script src="js/lib/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/library1.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Package.json simply looks like this:

```
{
  "name"    : "LosYork",
  "version" : "0.1.0",
  "main"    : "main.js"
}
```

and main.js is the electron file, which simply copies the code [from the quickstart](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/quick-start.md):

```
const electron = require('electron')
// Module to control application life.
const app = electron.app
// Module to create native browser window.
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let mainWindow

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/app/index.html')

  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null
  })
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

changing only the path to the index file (/app/index.html).

I know that I am not fully grasping the process of using node's "require", and I see in the quick start that there is a require statement happening in the [index file](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start/blob/master/index.html), as well as a code comment in [the bottom of main.js](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start/blob/master/main.js) saying that things can be required here as well, but if I try to include the scripts as require statements rather than just as , etc. I notice no difference.

A typical error I will see from a library dependent on jquery is, for example:

`jQuery is not defined`

in the lines:

```
(function(factory) {
    'use strict';
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(['jquery'], factory);
    } else if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
        module.exports = factory(require('jquery'));
    } else {
        factory(jQuery); //ERROR OCCURS HERE
    }

}(function($) {
  ...
}));
```

How do I include these libraries for electron so that they are available to each other in the app like they would in my normal web application?

Comment: Take a look at the issue https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/254